# Add entity to layer sketchup ruby api

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I've been searching for a while now on the internet how to add a certain entity to a layer in the ruby api but can't seem to find how to do this. Is there anybody that can help me?

Thanks in advance
Arne

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Drawingelement.layer=](http://ruby.sketchup.com/Sketchup/Drawingelement.html#layer%3D-instance_method) method. The sample code there should help.